# iOS: Issue modifying button's color

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, button

I have the following code in .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface SCLoginViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnLogin;
@end
```

and the following code in .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    // Add gradient to the buttons

    btnLogin.layer.cornerRadius = 10;

    CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientLayer.frame = btnLogin.layer.bounds;

    gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:0.1f].CGColor,
                            (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.4f alpha:0.5f].CGColor,
                            nil];

    gradientLayer.cornerRadius = btnLogin.layer.cornerRadius;
    [btnLogin.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];

    // Add shadow
    btnLogin.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
    btnLogin.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
    btnLogin.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0);
}
```

This is how the button sits on the screen:

[image]

Something is horribly wrong though. I know I am missing something simple, but can't figure it out. I created regular outlet called btnLogin but any change I try to make to it is not working. The button is rounded rect button. I tried Custom button and that didn't help.

Thank you!

Comment: How are you synthesizing `btnLogin`? Did you check with the debugger whether `btnLogin` is nil?

Comment: i have the following in .m file:

@synthesize btnLogin;

and looks like it is nil.

btnLogin UIButton * 0x00000000

Comment: Attach a debugger and check if `btnLogin` is nil. If so, then your outlet is not being correctly created when the xib file is instantiated at runtime. Ctrl-drag your button to the file owner again.

Answer (score 1):

From the image, I see that you did not make a connection from your btnLogin on the nib file to the file's owner - .h file.  So this line below has no connection to the button that you are trying to make changes.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnLogin;
```

Once you make that proper connection, it should show up the btnLogin name where Referencing Outlets is on the image you provided.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I have no idea why that happened... I just recreated it and it is there and it is working! Thank you!